# How do I index large objects in MongoDB? (What is stored in the index? Can I see the contents of the index?)

Tags: mongodb, indexing

If I insert this object into Mongo:

```
var object = {
  key1 : "some big string",
  key2 : "Another big inner object"
};
```

An `_id` is added automatically:

```
var object = {
   _id : objectId('some id');
   key1 : "some big string",
   key2 : "Another big inner object"
};
```

Of this new record, what parts of it are indexed (automatically or manually) and where is that index stored (RAM or disk)? If the data is stored in memory, how do I effectively index large objects? How can I see what is indexed?

Comment: Think a bit: if indices would be stored solely in RAM, it would have to be recreated each and every time a server is restarted – which, for complex indices and large collections – could take hours. They are _loaded_ into RAM, modified there as data changes and synced to disk from time to time. As for your other questions: it'd be nice if you [read the quite exhaustive documentation on indices](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/indexes/), before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

The only part which is indexed automatically is the `_id` field. Any other indexes need to be indexed manually.

Just like everything in MongoDB, indexes are handled as [memory-mapped files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file). That means the most recently used indexes are cached in RAM and get hibernated to hard drive when they aren't accessed for a while at the discretion of the operating system.

You can check what indexes you have on `your_collection` and how large they are with the Mongo shell command `db.your_collection.stats()`. When you want to know which fields are indexed by each index, use `db.your_collection.getIndexes()`